# shape mismatch with ProfileReport - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the library pandas_profiling to get data profiling. In particular, I am connecting to Postgres to get the data and then, create the profile.

```
#creating a new engine instance
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://dbname:password@host/db')
df = pd.read_sql_query('''select * from test''', engine)
report = ProfileReport(df, minimal=True) 
report.to_file("test.html")
```

However, I am getting this error: shape mismatch: value array of shape (105,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (106,). One solution that I know for sure would work is to split the dataset by columns and run the analysis, however, I would like to keep everything in one file. Have you experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @ashwani021994. For me, removing the columns with all values being NA works.

e.g.

```
df_new = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

And then, you can inspect what columns got removed which won't be useful in the ProfileReport anyways:

```
ls_cols_df = df.columns
ls_cols_df_new = df_new.dropna(axis=1, how='all').columns
print(set(ls_cols_df)-set(ls_cols_df_new))
```

Answer (score 0):

i was facing a similar error saying value array of shape (19,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (20,).

Please check for NaN values in your data, for me getting rid of them worked. Another thing that you can do is decreasing the size of your data. I was dealing with 4 million rows but tested it on 6000 rows , so first remove nan and then do profiling on small number of rows to test otherwise you will keep on waiting to understand what the error is. Do comment if it works for you or otherwise as i am curious to know what the main cause of this thing is and also share your insights. Thanks

Comment: The interesting part here is that if you click Run like X number of times, you can get lucky and your report will get generated. OK, will check your solution! Thank you!

Comment: But then, doesn't it defeat the purpose of data profiling? To remove the records?